# HTML Button: How to link a file outside a folder?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to find the path of the folder outside my current folder. I'm using a button to redirect to another page. But the page I want to redirect is outside the folder.

```
<input type="button" value="Back to Main Menu" onClick="location.href='./guestStart.php'" >
```

The file "guestStart.php" is outside the folder of the current page.

Does anybody know how? Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: outside which way?  higher (parent)? or lower (child)?   parents, you can use `../`

Comment: I want to redirect the page child(inner folder) to parent(outside folder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can get move backward by typing ../ as many time as you need to then specify your file
ie: if your index.php/html is in project1/date1/x1 and the file you want it to link is in project1/date3/x4 you will need to type

```
<a href="../../date3/x4/guestStart.php">link</a>
```