# Opening Local HTML Files using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a project I'm working on and I am trying to do file organisation with it

I want to open a html file in a folder before it.

Here is an example of the folder tree I am creating:

- Main Folder

  - Game_Folder

    - Rules

Each folder has a HTML, CSS and JS file in it (For organisation reasons). But I want to be able to open
'Game_Folder.html' from the 'Rules.html'. I know how to do it from the other way, I just cannot figure out how to do it backwards.

I cannot use a full directory (c:/) as it will be operated on a few different computers. So the file location must be in local file format (if that makes sense).

Thanks in Advance

-J

Comment: I would like to help you, but is is unclear what you're asking. What you have tried so far? And what do you mean by "open" HTML file?

Comment: Agreed, what do you mean by "open" the html? It sounds like you may not be very familiar with how webpages work. Normally, you've got a server running at your root directory, so if you ask it for `mysite.com/game/rules/rules.html`, it would serve the appropriate file, relative to your root.

Comment: `.` = current working directory *(not needed usually)*. `../` = up one level. `folderNameHere` = down a level. `folderNameHere/someFile.html` = down a level and access file. `../folderNameHere/someFile.html` = up a level down to the folder and access the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Navigating backwards using `..`

> Background info

I don't know if you are familiar with the command line but typing `cd ..` moves you backwards from one directory. This can also be used to reference files outside your current directory

> Presumed file layout

Presuming that your file layout is like this:

```
-> /Main_Folder
   -> index.html
   -> /Game_Folder
      -> game_folder.html
      -> /Rules_Folder
         -> rules.html
```

> Proposed solution

You can use this rule as below to reference your `game_folder.html` from your `rules.html`:

```
<a href="../game_folder.html">Click to open</a>
```

> Other resources

Some other things worth looking at are:
[This answer where I based my answer from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328762/html-button-how-to-link-a-file-outside-a-folder)

[This article from W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Also leave a comment if you have any questions